# How to remove anchor string after adding the initial field in docusign?

Tags: php, docusignapi

I am using this code for adding Initial field in docusign document. Field is populating perfectly but the anchor string is there behind the initial field.
I want to remove the anchor string after adding the initial field.

```
    $initialHereObjects = [];
    $initialHereTabs = [];

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
        $anchorString = '<<Doc' . $i . '.Initial>>'; 
        $initialHereObjects[] = $anchorString;
    }

    foreach ($initialHereObjects as $anchorStringInitialIndex => $anchorStringInitialValue) {
        $inital_here = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\InitialHere([
            'anchor_string' => "$anchorStringInitialValue", 'anchor_units' => 'pixels',
            'anchor_y_offset' => '10', 'anchor_x_offset' => '-8'
        ]);
        $initialHereTabs[] = $inital_here;
    }
    $signer->setTabs(
        new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs([
            'initial_here_tabs' => $initialHereTabs
        ])
    );
```

Comment: ***Welcome! Please check (accept) the best answer to your question. Thank you!!!***

Answer (score 0):

> I want to remove the anchor string

The anchor string is text that is in *your* document. DocuSign can't edit it, just search for it (and use it for tab placement).

Instead, we can suggest that, in *your* document, the author of the document can make the anchor string invisible. Do this by choosing the text color to be the same as the document's background color (white). That way DocuSign will see it for tag processing but it won't be visible in the signing ceremony.